# Trying to access two arrays in JSON with $.each

Tags: jquery, json

I am having a hard time accessing both values in an array. Im not sure what I am doing wrong. basically I just want to output both images and display them on the page. Hope someone can help me with this. Below is my code:

```js
(function() {
 
 'use strict';

     var url = 'path to json';
    
     $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        
         //store json data into variable 
      var data = (json);
 
   //store data in empty string
   var images = '';
 
   //retrieve values from json file
   $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    images += '<img src="' + item[i].imageURL + '">';
      });
  
   //append results to div
 
   $('#images').html(images);
  
     });
  
 })();
```

Comment: for such a simple array, why do you need a loop? `data[1].category`, `data[0].imageURL`

Comment: thats just a minified version of the json file, its going to have like 300 + sub arrays like above with images etc

Comment: in that case i need a loop but i cant figure it out. when i do data[0] in the loop i only get the first arrays image. i want to be able to access both and have it loop and print both of them. thanks for your help!

Comment: then, assuming that the two arrays are exactly parallel, you can use the `i` index you get from the array you're looping on to get at the equivalent data in the OTHER array.

Comment: can you please show me an example? based on the above

Comment: `data[1][i].category` or whatever. you should show a snippet of your ACTUAL array with more than just one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are 2 possible fields which could contain the image path, select the correct one. In addition, use `item[0]` since the nested array has `length=1`:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var url = 'path to json';

  $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

    //store json data into variable 
    var data = (json);

    //store data in empty string
    var images = '';

    //retrieve values from json file
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      images += '<img src="' + (item[0].imageURL || item[0].category) + '">';
    });

    //append results to div

    $('#images').html(images);
  });
})();
```

Comment: thats what i was trying to begin with. for some reason the images show up blank. for other examples i have had to use $.each(data[0] etc to access the approriate array

Comment: [
   [
       {
           "imageURL":"path to image",
       }
   ],
   [
       {
           "category":"path to image",  
       }
   ]
]

Comment: @Tom Ok seeing the data structure, I updated my answer to show a way to add the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.You are missing to access the contents by i
check the following code snippet

```js
var img=[
   [
       {
           "imageURL":"path to image",
       }
   ],
   [
       {
           "category":"path to image",  
       }
   ]
];
$.each(img, function (i, item) {
  alert(item[i].imageURL)
var images = '<img src="' + item[i].imageURL + '">';
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have my updated code above but I still dont know why it doesnt want to work for me.

Comment: It wont work because in one of the arrays you have imageUrl and in another you dont have it ...you should check the accessibility of it and then use it

Comment: that other category is supposed to say imageURL as well. i just messed up. but the above example tcooc solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that your json is bad formated, but ...

```
    var ri = [
   [
       {
           "imageURL":"path to image",
       }
   ],
   [
       {
           "category":"path to image",  
       }
   ]
];
$(ri).each(function(i, n){
  if('imageURL' in n[i]){
    console.log(n[i]['imageURL']);
  }
});
```